# Split and save master powerpoint presenation into indvidual slide with filename on header of each slide

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I have a master presentation with 20 slides. I want to create a macro to quickly split the slide 3 to 20 into individual slide. Then save it on the same folder with file name taken from each slide title/header.

I found this code online but it splite every slides and save with different file names. Please help. Thanks a lot in advance.

```
Option Explicit
Sub TestMe()
    SaveAllSlides "C:\Users\domino\Desktop\3_PPT\PPT_Macro\PAT_upgrade.pptx", True
End Sub

Sub SaveAllSlides(ByVal newFilename As String, _
                  Optional ByVal keepOpen As Boolean = False)
    Dim dotPosition As Long
    dotPosition = InStrRev(newFilename, ".")
    If dotPosition = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The filename is missing the pptx extension"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Dim filepathNoExt As String
    filepathNoExt = Left$(newFilename, dotPosition - 1)

    Dim newPresentation As Presentation
    Dim thisPresentation As Presentation
    Set thisPresentation = ActivePresentation

    Dim i As Long
    For i = 1 To ActivePresentation.Slides.Count
        Set newPresentation = Presentations.Add
        thisPresentation.Slides(i).Copy
        With newPresentation
            .Slides.Paste Index:=1
            .Slides(1).Design = thisPresentation.Slides(i).Design
            .Slides(1).ColorScheme = thisPresentation.Slides(i).ColorScheme
            .SaveAs FileName:=filepathNoExt & Format(i, "00") & ".pptx"
            If Not keepOpen Then
                .Close
            End If
        End With
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: "I found this code online" Don't expect a quick answer here because you're feeling lazy. Do a search on _PowerPoint VBA get slide title_ Modify your code as best you can. Then we'll help you to debug it.

Comment: Something is not clear: what do you mean you want to split slide 3 into 20 slides? do you actually mean FROM slide 3?

Comment: Good good and thinking

Comment: good good and thinking ")